# Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail Still User Not Found

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail for forgot password in API, why does it still return `User not found`, i log user find use`same _id` and i found that user, but in `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` still not found

```
 let checkEmail = Meteor.users.findOne({"emails.0.address": json.email}); 
     if (checkEmail) { 
        let email = json.email; let userId = checkEmail._id; 
        Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail({userId,email},
        function(err, ress) { 
             if (err) { 
                 return Meteor.call('apiResponse', '400' ,res.error); 
             }else { 
                 return 'success'; 
             } 
         }) 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` with the wrong arguments, it should be this:

```
Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail(userId, email);
```